# Unbind an event from Document : jquery

Tags: jquery, bind, unbind

Binding a function on document all element having class SearchableCol

```
jQuery(document).on("click", ".SearchableCol", nwcsClickFunc);
```

I am trying below two methods to unbind, nothing is working.

```
jQuery(document).unbind("click", nwcsClickFunc);
jQuery(".SearchableCol").unbind("click");
```

Need help to unbind an event from document.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(document).off("click", ".SearchableCol", nwcsClickFunc);
```

or use namespaced event handlers

```
jQuery(document).on("click.myevent", ".SearchableCol", nwcsClickFunc);
```

then

```
jQuery(document).off("click.myevent", ".SearchableCol");
```

Comment: I also tried jQuery(document).on("click", ".SearchableCol").unbind(); and it also worked but off is better thanks......

Answer (score 3):

```
jQuery(document).off("click", ".SearchableCol", nwcsClickFunc);
```

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
$(".SearchableCol").unbind('click',nwcsClickFunc);
```

or

```
$(document).off('click','.SearchableCol',nwcsClickFunc);
```

Comment: the first one won't work for delegated event, handler bound to document level, not to ".SearchableCol" elements

Comment: @A.Wolff: Not sure how it should be used. :\

Comment: Not sure to understand your comment, but your second solution is what OP is looking for ;) Remove the first and get a +1

Comment: What i mean is, is it possible to remove delegated events(on,live) using undelegate.

Comment: ya, using namespace: `jQuery(document).off('click.namespace');` or just `jQuery(document).off('click');` but that will remove all click handlers bound to document

Comment: Sorry forgot this one of course: `jQuery(document).off('click',nwcsClickFunc);` but again, not specific to `.SearchableCol` elements